# Better understand SQLalchemy's `yield_per()` problems

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

To cite [SQLalchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per):

> The Query.yield_per() method is not compatible with most eager loading schemes, including subqueryload and joinedload with collections.
>
> Warning
>
> Use this method with caution; if the same instance is present in more than one batch of rows, end-user changes to attributes will be overwritten.
>
> In particular, it’s usually impossible to use this setting with eagerly loaded collections (i.e. any lazy=’joined’ or ‘subquery’) since those collections will be cleared for a new load when encountered in a subsequent result batch. In the case of ‘subquery’ loading, the full result for all rows is fetched which generally defeats the purpose of yield_per().
>
> Also note that while yield_per() will set the stream_results execution option to True, currently this is only understood by psycopg2 dialect which will stream results using server side cursors instead of pre-buffer all rows for this query. Other DBAPIs pre-buffer all rows before making them available. The memory use of raw database rows is much less than that of an ORM-mapped object, but should still be taken into consideration when benchmarking.

I really have a problem understanding how `yield_per()` works and what exactly is the problem on using this method. Also what is the right way to workaround these problems and keep using this function for iterating over a huge amount of rows.

I'm interested in all constructive information you have, but here are some hint questions:

- How can there be multiple instances of the same row? Only through relationships (if two rows of the iterating table have an FK to the same row in another table)? Is there a problem if you do not know that it happens or you only read attributes on the relationships?
- lazy=’joined’ or ‘subquery’ are not possible, but why exactly? Both of them are simply parts of your query on which you call `yield_per()`.

  - If they are cleared in a subsequent result batch, then simply load it again. So where is the problem? Or is the only problem that you loose the changes of you're relationships if have made changes?
  - In the case of a ‘subquery’ loading, why all rows are fetched? The SQL Server may have to save a big table, but then why not simply return the result in batches one after the other for the entire query?
  - In an example in the [`yield_per()` doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per) `q = sess.query(Object).yield_per(100).options(lazyload('*'), joinedload(Object.some_related))` they deactivate eagerload with `lazyload('*')` but keep a single joined load. Is there a way to still use `yield_per()` with eagerload? What are the conditions?
- They say `psycopg2` is the only DBAPI which support stream results. So is that the only DBAPI which you can use with `yield_per()`? As far as I understand `yield_per` uses the `cursor.fetchmany()` ([example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchmany.html)) function of DBAPI which support many of them. And as far as I understand `cursor.fetchmany()` supports fetching only parts of the result and does not fetch everything (If it would fetch everything, why the function exists?)
- I have the feeling that `yield_per()` is entirely safe (even with eagerload) if you only do read access (for example for statistics). Is that correct?

Answer (score 16):

Both of the problematic loading strategies raise exceptions if you try to use them with `yield_per`, so you don't really have to worry too much.

I *believe* the only problem with `subqueryload` is that batched loading of the second query isn't implemented (yet).  Nothing would go wrong semantically, but if you're using `yield_per`, you probably have a really good reason not to want to load all the results at once.  So SQLAlchemy politely refuses to go against your wishes.

`joinedload` is a little more subtle.  It's only forbidden in the case of a collection, where a primary row might have multiple associated rows.  Say your query produces raw results like this, where A and B are primary keys from different tables:

```
 A | B 
---+---
 1 | 1 
 1 | 2 
 1 | 3 
 1 | 4 
 2 | 5 
 2 | 6
```

Now you fetch these with `yield_per(3)`.  The problem is that SQLAlchemy can only limit how much it fetches by *rows*, but it has to return *objects*.  Here, SQLAlchemy only sees the first three rows, so it creates an `A` object with key 1 and *three* `B` children: 1, 2, and 3.

When it loads the next batch, it wants to create a new `A` object with key 1...  ah, but it already has one of those, so no need to create it again.  The extra `B`, 4, is lost.  (So, no, even reading joined collections with `yield_per` is unsafe — chunks of your data might go missing.)

You might say "well, just keep reading rows until you have a full object" — but what if that `A` has a hundred children?  Or a million?  SQLAlchemy can't reasonably guarantee that it can do what you asked *and* produce correct results, so it refuses to try.

---

Remember that the DBAPI is designed so that *any* database can be used with the same API, even if that database doesn't support all the DBAPI features.  Consider that the DBAPI is designed around cursors, but MySQL doesn't actually *have* cursors!  The DBAPI adapters for MySQL have to fake them, instead.

So while `cursor.fetchmany(100)` will *work*, you can see from [the `MySQLdb` source code](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L426) that it doesn't fetch lazily from the server; it fetches everything into one big list, then returns a slice when you call `fetchmany`.

What `psycopg2` supports is true streaming, where the results are remembered *persistently* on the server, and your Python process only sees a few of them at a time.

You can still use `yield_per` with `MySQLdb`, or any other DBAPI; that's the whole point of the DBAPI's design.  You'll have to pay the memory cost for all the raw rows hidden away in the DBAPI (which are tuples, fairly cheap), but you won't *also* have to pay for all of the ORM objects at the same time.

Answer (score -4):

Becareful that sometime yield_per will fail, not sure about the root case is yield_per or not. (U can test by setting the yield number as a magic number, such as 51, 17)

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

DB: mysql:5.7.0